# Add listener when autocomplete component suggestion panel closes in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

M using autocomplete in angular 2, what I want to do is, when autocomplete suggestion panel closes then some function should be called. Can some one tell me how to do that. M thinking of event listener but don't know how to use on it.

Comment: using material2? and when you have selected some option? or when you click outside of the input box ?

Comment: When I click outside of box and on suggestion panel.

Comment: then see my answer and demo that I have linked.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Angular Material 2, then you can use the `(optionSelected)` event:

```
<md-autocomplete #auto="mdAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="onOptionSelected($event)">
```

Otherwise, you can use `(focusout)` event on the input:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Pick one" (focusout)="panelClosed($event)">
```

See this [**working demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-zcmcct?file=app/app.component.html).

Comment: You can't use the (optionSelected) in case it was closed without a selection, e.g. the user pressed out site of the element, you should use(focusout).

Answer (score 0):

In the link below you have a list of possible DOM eventLister.
I would use 'onfocusout' in the textfield.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp